# Error: incorrect number of arguments to constructor

Tags: solidity, polygon, smartcontracts, hardhat

I am facing this problem while running my Solidity code in Hardhat. It worked fine in Remix and I even used the contract for quite some time, but when deploying the contract through Hardhat on Matic I am getting this error.

This is my Contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Lock {

    mapping(address => uint256) public tickets;
    mapping(address => uint256) public time1;


    function assign(uint256 newValue) public {
        uint256 oldValue = tickets[msg.sender];
        tickets[msg.sender] = oldValue + newValue;
        time1[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
    }

    function reduce() public {
        require(tickets[msg.sender] > 0, "No more tickets");
        uint256 oldValue = tickets[msg.sender];
        tickets[msg.sender] = oldValue - 1;
    }

    function setTickets(uint256 add, address key) public {
        tickets[key] = tickets[key] + add;
    }

    function getTime(address key) public view returns(uint256){
        return time1[key];
    }

    function getTickets(address key) public view returns(uint256){
        return tickets[key];
    }

}
```

This is my hardhat.config.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");

module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "matic",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    matic: {
      url: "https://rpc-mainnet.maticvigil.com",
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.9",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
}
```

The Error:

```
Error: incorrect number of arguments to constructor
    at ContractFactory.getDeployTransaction (/Users/risavdebpatra/Desktop/Carnival_hardhat/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/factory.ts:87:19)
    at ContractFactory.deploy (/Users/risavdebpatra/Desktop/Carnival_hardhat/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/factory.ts:105:31)
    at deployContract (/Users/risavdebpatra/Desktop/Carnival_hardhat/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:385:18)
    at main (/Users/risavdebpatra/Desktop/Carnival_hardhat/scripts/deploy.js:15:16)
```

I have no clue why this is happening and would appreciate some help from the experts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  In my constructor() in the solidity contract I need to pass a uint to set a protocol fee which was obvious in Remix.  I fixed this in Hardhat by doing

```
const contract = await ContractFactory.deploy('uintValue')
```

I don't see a constructor in your contract.  It's not clear if you didn't include it in your question or if you don't have one.

You also didn't include your deploy.js code which would be helpful.